# Is it possible to prevent people from entering data into my Google Spreadsheet?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

Is it possible that I fix the order of user's entries with a script? For example, the user must fill cell `A1` first, only after that he can fill cell `A2`.

Maybe my explanation is better with an example template from me: [Reading scheduler](https://drive.google.com/previewtemplate?id=0ArZUoMmLrRA6dEF5WWY1dHBqZDdDRjNRa0t5SDNIOEE&mode=public)﻿

<sup>Question on Google+ community: https://plus.google.com/110138757494391019716/posts/U91woskXd8C</sup>

Answer (score 1):

With the code below you can have a fairly responsive interaction with the user.

### Code

```
function onEdit(e) {
  // allow book name to be added
  var cell = e.range.getA1Notation();  
  if(cell == "A7") {
    return;
  }

  // only if conditional color is present
  var color = e.range.getBackground(); 
  if(cell != "A7" && (color == "#cfe2f3" || color == "white")) {
    var first = e.range.offset(-1,-1).getValue(); 
    var second = e.range.offset(-1,0).getValue();

    // first entry
    if(typeof first == "string" && second == "Current") {
      return;
    } 

    // non consecutive weeks
    if(typeof first == "number" && typeof second == "string") {
      respond(e, "Not consecutive enty !!");
    } 

    // out of range  
    if(first == "") {
      respond(e, "This entry is out of range");
    }
  } else {
    respond(e, "Out of bounds");
  }
}

function respond(e, text) {
  e.range.clearContent();
  e.source.toast(text);
  return;
}
```

### Example

I've created an example file for you: **[Copy of Reading scheduler](https://docs.google.com/a/familietuinstra.nl/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0ApDwwZxW-IBcdFk1TmlOeVJTYkYyX2Uta05pdnVvX2c&usp=sharing)**.
See also revised code for removing data.

Comment: Wow, thank you very much. I try to understand your code,
because it don't work 100%, unfortunately. If I put in cell J12 then I can put in cell J13.
In my idea after J12 it should be able to fill cell N12, only.
Because the the user should start with week 1, also row 12.
But maybe I can live with this code. But, the biggest problem is, after I use my 'Reset' button,
I can't fill 'Number of weeks' and 'Pages'.

Comment: @carlos030 So, I've prepared it vertically and you want it horizontally (which makes sence)?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the submission by @JacobJanTuinstra, have you considered using a form entry system, as opposed to a script? If I understand your question properly, you have required data entries from user, that must be completed before they can move on to update the others. Why not make a form, with required fields, that exports its responses to the target spreadsheet? That way, the form will not allow submission without all required fields being filled out.

Comment: @pnuts  what? No, I'm suggesting exactly what I posted. Make a form, with required fields, that exports it's responses to the target spreadsheet. Why would you need to make a form for every cell? That doesn't even make sense. When you create a form, you can select which fields in the form are necessary, and which aren't. It will not allow you to submit the form if all fields marked required are not filled out.

Comment: @pnuts, perhaps I am over-thinking the OP's question, but it seems to me what they are trying to do is ensure that all data is entered accurately in necessary cells. My approach is irrespective of order, so it may not be feasible for their needs if they truly require "cell ax, cell ax+1, cell ax+2" entry order. I merely offered the option.